# Importing GFF file with Biopython

Tags: python, phylogenetics, genbank, gff

Is there a way to import a GFF file for an organism with Biopython in the same way you can for a Genbank file?

For example,

```
from Bio import Entrez as ez
ez.email = '...'
handle = ez.efetch(db='gene', id='AE015451.2', rettype='genbank', retmode='xml')
h = handle.read()
print(h)
```

This will import a Gebank xml file for Pseudomonas putida.  Is there a way to do this for a GFF file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, [there is currently no GFF support in biopython](https://biopython.org/wiki/GFF_Parsing).

[However, you can read in GFF files into python using this package, gffutils](https://github.com/daler/gffutils). There are also a few other packages to read/write GFF files, like [`gff3`](https://pypi.org/project/gff3/).

Answer (score 2):

I would use `BCBio` for gff handling as it is written to directly interface with BioPython’s object model.

The only downside is that I believe it is no longer actively supported. It is however the package that the [BioPython docs](https://biopython.org/wiki/GFF_Parsing) use generally. There are plans to properly incorporate GFF/GTF parsers in to BP in the not too distant future according to that link though.

Answer (score 1):

Most GFF parsers handle the work of reading annotation data into objects for convenient data access, but most do not handle the important task of resolving relationships between features. The [**tag** Python library](https://tag.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) does both, grouping related features together for inspection, traversal, and feature-by-feature processing.

**CAVEAT**: The tag library only supports GFF3.

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm the developer of the tag library, so this is a shameless plug. :-)